# Get Twin Primes as output from an inputted list

Tags: python, list, primes

I want to enter numbers separated by spaces as input and store them in a list. I want to get all twin primes in that list as output. If there's no any twin primes in that inputted numbers I want to have an output `"No any twin primes"`.

*Twin Prime - two prime numbers whose difference is 2*

So my code was like this:

```
lst = input()
test_list =[]

for ele in lst.split():
    n_int = int(ele)
    test_list.append(n_int)

def prime(x):
    for k in range(2, x):
        if x%k == 0:
            return False
    return True

diff = 0
for i in test_list:
    for j in test_list:
        if prime(i) and prime(j):
            diff = abs(i-j)
        if diff == 2:
            print(i, j)
        
print("No any twin primes")
```

If I input a number series like `3 4 5 7 8`, I expect an output

```
3 5
5 7
```

but my output was

```
3 5
5 3
5 4
5 7
5 9
7 5
No any twin primes
```

If there's no any twin primes in the inputted list (`2 3 7 9`) I get my expected output as

```
No any twin primes
```

.

Comment: It's doing what you tell it to do. For example, it ALWAYS prints "No any twin primes" no matter what -- because you tell it to. You really need to just follow it in a debugger. Look at the value of diff. Look at the i, j pairs you are testing. Have you considered using itertools?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Changes made:**

(1) Created a `res` as a list which stores the **Twin primes**

(2) iteration of inner for loop is from `i+1` to `end`

**Code:-**

```
lst = input("Enter the numbers: ")
test_list =[]

for ele in lst.split():
    n_int = int(ele)
    test_list.append(n_int)

def prime(x):
    for k in range(2, x):
        if x%k == 0:
            return False
    return True

diff = 0
res=[]
for i in range(len(test_list)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(test_list)):
        if prime(test_list[i]) and prime(test_list[j]):
            diff = abs(test_list[i]-test_list[j])
            if diff == 2:
                res.append([test_list[i],test_list[j]])
if res: 
    for i,j in res:
        print(i,j)
else:
    print("No any twin primes")
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter the numbers: 3 4 5 7 8
3 5
5 7

Enter the numbers: 2 3 7 9
No any twin primes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It works !!! Can you please explain why there's a need for another list (res).  It's not clear for me.

Comment: It is basically used so that we know if there is nothing in the list means there contains no twin prime number..! which is checked using `if else` @Se00

Comment: if we directly `prints` the result we can't say that we have find the twin prime or not. by storing in any datatype if it is empty we can say there is no twin prime if it is not empty we can say there must be atleast1 twin prime so that we don't need to print `No any twin primes` hope you understand it.. @Se00

Answer (score -2):

Here's my try:

```
def twinPrimes(iter):
    primes = []
    res = []
    for i in iter:
        for j in range(2, int(i/2)+1):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(i)
    for i in range(len(primes)-1):
        if primes[i+1] - 2 == primes[i]:
            res.append((primes[i], primes[i+1]))
    if res == []:
        return "No any twin primes"
    else:
        return res
print(twinPrimes([3,5,7]))
```

You can also change the return to printing like:

```
def twinPrimes(iter):
    primes = []
    res = []
    for i in iter:
        for j in range(2, int(i/2)+1):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            primes.append(i)
    for i in range(len(primes)-1):
        if primes[i+1] - 2 == primes[i]:
            res.append((primes[i], primes[i+1]))
            print(primes[i], primes[i+1])
    if res == []:
        print("No any twin primes")
```

Input: `twinPrimes([3,5,7])`
Output:

```
3 5
5 7
```

Input: `twinPrimes([2,5,9])`
Output:

```
No any twin primes
```